# How to assign value to an empty dataframe with multiindexes columns with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create an empty dataframe with multiindexes columns with Pandas, and then fill values later on. How could I do that ?

In this example I can create the dataframe but can't assign value to it with `.loc`.

```
segment = 'segment_1'
tuples = [(segment, 'market', 'symbol'),
          (segment, 'market', 'base'),
          (segment, 'market', 'quote'),
          (segment, 'market', 'wallet'),
          (segment, 'market', 'type'),
          (segment, 'market', 'margined'),
          (segment, 'market', 'derivative'),
          (segment, 'funds', 'wallet'),
          (segment, 'funds', 'code'),
          (segment, 'type', 'action'),
          (segment, 'type', 'transfer'),
          (segment, 'type', 'priority'),
         ]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["level_1", "level_2", 'level_3'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=index)
df.loc[:, ('segment_1', 'market', 'symbol')] = 1
df

level_1 segment_1
level_2 market  funds   type
level_3 symbol  base    quote   wallet  type    margined    derivative  wallet  code    action  transfer    priority
```

As you can it's not possible to set value to this dataframe. What is the reason for this ? do I need to create an index first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is used `:` in `loc` for select all rows, but because rows not exist is not set value. So solution is set index label like `0` here:

```
df.loc[0, ('segment_1', 'market', 'symbol')] = 1

print (df)
level_1 segment_1                                                         \
level_2    market                                             funds        
level_3    symbol base quote wallet type margined derivative wallet code   
0               1  NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN      NaN        NaN    NaN  NaN   

level_1                           
level_2   type                    
level_3 action transfer priority  
0          NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: So there is no need to create an index, thank you it exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Florent - Before not, `index` is created in `loc`.